# why can i only know conductance and susceptance,not impedance from open-circuit test?

Tags: transformer, resistance, impedance

1.open-circuit test determine the electrical conductance and susceptance,not impedance

2.close-circuit test determine the  impedance ,not  electrical conductance and susceptance

First,i want to ask that we know the  difference between open-circuit and close-circuit  is that secondary of the transformer is open-circuited or close-circuited,and as we know conductance =1/resistance,that is ,i should know the impedance ,resistance, conductance and susceptance  no matter circuit i used.so why can i only know conductance and susceptance,not impedance from open-circuit test?

Comment: What you directly measure is the admittance. You can then calculate the impedance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw the circuit of a lossy transformer to understand your question.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJOSq0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To measure the approximate value of the impedance \$Z\$, use a short circuit test.

To measure the approximate value of the admittance \$Y\$, use an open circuit test.